# How to update/save document that include referance using morphia for mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

So i have the following class:

```
@Entity("Item")
@ToString(callSuper=true, includeFieldNames=true)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Item {

    public Item() {
        this.timestamp = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private ObjectId id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private UUID timestamp; 


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Reference (lazy=false)
    private GeneralInfo generalInfo;    

}
```

while trying to save/update the item into mongodb, i have to first save the generalInfo class first and only then i can save the item class. i get it that the tables are dependand now, but is there a way to let morphia/mongo know what i want to use "deep update / save" or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Morphia does not support cascading saves like that.  The use of references is largely orthogonal to the recommended way to model your domain (we encourage/recommend embedding documents) so supporting such a feature doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Got it. its s shame that they dont have it.. but i guess there is nothing to do. thanks. (I do have some other classes with embeded annotation) the thing is that you lossing all the benefits of refereance tables wise :|